# Feature request/suggestion: Segmented styled asking format

Tags: feature-request, markdown

### Background

So this is really just directed more towards newer posters. Most of the time the questions are basically a wall of text, with code, problems and expected results all intermingled which makes it hard to follow top to bottom what they're looking for. So what I'm proposing is, rather than an empty textbox without without direction, have segments which gives the poster some guide on how to ask and what to actually put there.

### Suggestion

Have three blocks:

- **What I have** (this should be some background with code, could split this into two section, where one section provides more written info about the situation and the other section is more code related)
- **What I'm getting** (result currently outputted, probably no code)
- **What I want** (expected result, probably no code)

See an example of how I formatted one of my questions: [react - how to pass event from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44559954/6554121)

Of course, this should only be forced on newer users (maybe 50 and under rep like comments). And anyone else can have free text as we do now, though with the option of using the segmented format as well.

### Implementation

Something like this:

```js
var title = ["What I have", "What I'm getting", "What I want"];
var hints = ["Give information on the background and provide code", "Post what results you're getting from provided code/situation", "Post what results you are expecting to receive"];
var text = Array(3).fill("");
var index = 0;

(function() {
 $("#title").html(title[index]);
  $("#hint").html(hints[index]);
  $("#text").val(text[index]);
})();

function change(dir)
{
 text[index] = $("#text").val();
  
 if (dir === "prev")
  {
    if (index)
    {
      index--;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    if (index < 2)
    {
      index++;
    }
  }
  
 $("#title").html(title[index]);
  $("#hint").html(hints[index]);  
  $("#text").val(text[index]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="title">
  
  </div>
  <div id="hint">
    
  </div>
  <textarea id="text">
    
  </textarea>
</div>
<button onclick="change('prev')">
prev
</button>
<button onclick="change('next')">
next
</button>
```